# How to proc import from uncleaned csv file / different format input variables & Title in the file?

Tags: import, format, sas

My input file is in "CSV" but I have 2 problems here

### 1. My variable name start in line3 , how can I write the code to start reading name from line3  and take value from line4 ?

### 2. acct_num has some typo ( space , - dash )  this force error in the process, so I couldn't get the file import to sasdataset. ( I know I do this in sasdataset , but not sure how can I get this import to SAS)

```
PROC IMPORT DATAFILE="c:\temp\bad.csv" OUT=table1 DBMS=CSV REPLACE;
    GETNAMES=YES;
    DATAROW=2;
RUN;
```

---

```
line1   Title_name  
line2       
line3   acct_name   acct_num
line4   A          12345
line5   B          12    345
line6   C          12-345
line7   D          1234
line8   E          123
```

---

SAS dummy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't get the import to do what you wanted, maybe another answer will help with PROC IMPORT....however, you can use an INFILE statement. This solution assumes you know your variable names.

Assuming your file looks something like this:

```
title_name

acct_name,acct_num
A,12345
B,12    345
C,12-345
D,1234
E,123
```

the below code will start reading on line 4.

```
filename csv "C:\Documents and Settings\jsc\Desktop\csv_infile.csv";

data Work.temp;

 infile csv dlm=',' dsd missover lrecl=1000 firstobs=4;
 input acct_name $ acct_num $ ;

 <code to fix any values in acct_name or acct_num, if any>

run;
```

Update your question with additional questions if this is an acceptable solution and you need help maninpulating the data that is read in.